# Azure Containers for Orchestration, {functionname}-applease and testhubname-applease, Expired

Tags: azure-functions, orchestration

I have an Azure Orchestration Function running every minute for the last several months. Randomly it seems, a few weeks ago, the containers that are created automatically for Orchestration, `{functionname}-applease` and `testhubname-applease`, expired. Now, the orchestration never triggers because the underlying blob is in an `Archive` state which generates the error:

> This operation is not permitted on an archived blob.

The process has been running constantly. Luckily, this happened in our dev environment so production has not been impacted (yet) but I do have production `Orchestration` functions that follow the same patterns.

I did not set these to archive and these are the containers automatically created by using `Orchestration` functions. To me it seems like since they were automatically created by instantiating the `Orchestration` functions, something must've happened for Azure to move them to an `Archived` blob with an `Expired` Lease State on the container. I just don't know what.

When I look at our production `Lease States` for similar `Orchestration` functions, I see they are `Lease State: Leased`, `Lease Status: Locked` and `Lease Duration: Fixed`. I do not see a `Lease Duration` date.

Do I need to renew the leases in code every `Orchestration` function run? Or is there some setting to set so these containers won't just stop working when they randomly expire on some arbitrary date?

Answer (score 0):

We had a Lifecycle defined for the container that moved unmodified blobs to lower tiers based on a date range. Since it was running, I would've thought it would've been updating the blobs but it was just reading since it wasn't scaling up or out or anything so it ended up getting caught by the Lifecyle Management and moved to Archive.